# OpenJDK, IcedTea security settings

Tags: java, security, gui, openjdk, icedtea

I am a beginner Linux user. From my knowledge the system uses OpenJDK and IcedTea only when I connect to a SAP IDES server through SAP GUI JAVA adding a string in it to connect to that server. I use SAP for my studies. 
[What is SAP IDES](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/4d/848a08fc4c11d1a5760060087d1a6b/content.htm)

I have the next 3 questions please, I will number them to be easier for you to answer:

1. How can I check if only the SAP GUI JAVA from all Lubuntu and other installed applications need and use the OpenJDK and IcedTea.
2. If only SAP GUI JAVA from my entire system needs OpenJDK and IcedTea, are there any security settings using these two commands `itweb-settings` and `IcedTea-Web` or using other commands to set the OpenJDK or IcedTea to accept connections to them only from SAP GUI JAVA, and only from the IDES server please?
3. Which other security settings do you recommend to set to OpenJDK and IcedTea, like filtering the IDES and SAP connection?

Edit: After  David Foerster comment, "It think this question is too broad and lacks quite a bit of vital information" I've tried to delete what I supposed it could be "vital information"

Thank you very much and all the best to you all !

Comment: It think this question is too broad and lacks quite a bit of vital information. Unfortunately I can't vote to close it because of its open bounty.

Comment: David Foerster, thank you for your replay, can you give some more details please?